# Change CSS of element when hovering over other element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to alter the CSS of an element when the user hovers over another element - pure CSS no JS.

I am sure it's possible, i'm sure i've done it before....just can't get it to work now.

I have two DIVs.

One already has box shadow and the other not.

When the user hovers over the one with no shadow, I want that DIV to get box-shadow and the other one to lose it's shadow....And the vice versa to happen when the user takes mouse off the second DIV.

```
.div1 {background: #24D4F9;-webkit-box-shadow: -3px 8px 29px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: -3px 8px 29px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: -3px 8px 29px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);}

.div2{} /* No Shadwow */

.div2:hover {-webkit-box-shadow: -3px 8px 29px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); 
-moz-box-shadow: -3px 8px 29px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: -3px 8px 29px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);} /* This bit works */

.div2:hover .div1{-webkit-box-shadow: -3px 8px 29px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0);
-moz-box-shadow: -3px 8px 29px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0);
box-shadow: -3px 8px 29px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0);} /* This bit doesn't work */
```

What's the correct way to write the last bit?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the markup? does your DIV1 resides inside DIV2?

Comment: `.div2:hover .div1` will try to match any `.div1` element that is a child to a `hovered` `.div2`. Please can you provide your HTML.

Comment: Look harder for other answers. There are about a dozen of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order of the div's and then it is possible :)
http://jsfiddle.net/zcw8bdnq/

HTML:

```
<div class="div2">Test text div 2</div>
<div class="div1">Test text div 1</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div1, .div2 {
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.div1 {background: #24D4F9;-webkit-box-shadow: -3px 8px 29px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: -3px 8px 29px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: -3px 8px 29px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);}

.div2{}

.div2:hover + .div1 {-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0);}

.div2:hover {-webkit-box-shadow: -3px 8px 29px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); 
-moz-box-shadow: -3px 8px 29px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: -3px 8px 29px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);}
```